# align comma separated blocks in C uncrustify

Tags: c, uncrustify

I have been looking into uncrustify configuration but I can't find the option that turns this:

```
    uint8_t reg_values[] = {OP_MODE, 0x00,
                    B_CURRENT, 0xDC,
                    G_CURRENT, 0xC8,
                    R_CURRENT, 0xF0,
                    LED_MAP, 0x00};
```

into this:

```
    uint8_t reg_values[] = {OP_MODE,   0x00,
                            B_CURRENT, 0xDC,
                            G_CURRENT, 0xC8,
                            R_CURRENT, 0xF0,
                            LED_MAP,   0x00};
```

and this:

```
    fsm_transition_t transition_table[] = {
        {     INIT,     INIT, init_func,     write_init_cmd},
        {     INIT,     IDLE,    done,               NULL},
        {     IDLE, SHUTDOWN,       is_shutdown,          power_off},
        {-1, -1, NULL, NULL},
    };
```

into this:

```
    fsm_transition_t transition_table[] = {
        {     INIT,     INIT,   init_func,          write_cmd},
        {     INIT,     IDLE,        done,               NULL},
        {     IDLE, SHUTDOWN, is_shutdown,          power_off},
        {       -1,       -1,        NULL,               NULL},
    };
```

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: That's not relevant, since I am using uncrustify for the code formatting.